# Copying random folders stopping to soon

Tags: batch-file, random, copy, directory

I'm making a script that copies random folders from source to destination until that folder is full (knowing that the destination folder is smaller then the source.

All the individual parts are working as intended, but I'm now running the script without the copy included (just an echo) so basically if there aren't any folders larger then the remaining space in the destination directory, it should be running for ever.

But it stops at an average of 5 iterations while there isn't any folder large enough to fill up the directory. This is the code I'm using

EDIT: got it olmost working, but now sometimes a needed_space outputs 0

```
@ECHO off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET n=0
SET SOURCE_PATH=M:\Movies
SET DEST_PATH=E:\Movies

:: get all folders in dir
FOR /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`DIR /b/a:d %SOURCE_PATH%`) do (
    SET /A n+=1     
    SET folder[!n!]=%%a
)


:loop
    :: selecting ranodm number
    SET /A rand=(n*%random%)/32768+1

    :: check for space
    for /F "tokens=3" %%S in ('dir /-c "%SOURCE_PATH%\!folder[%rand%]!\*" ^| findstr /c:"File(s)"') DO set NEEDED_SPACE=%%S
    FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%i IN ('fsutil volume diskfree %DEST_PATH%') DO SET FREE_SPACE=%%j

    ECHO %FREE_SPACE% - %NEEDED_SPACE%
    IF %NEEDED_SPACE% GTR %FREE_SPACE% GOTO done

    :: check if file does not exits
    IF EXIST %DEST_PATH%\!folder[%rand%]! GOTO loop 

    :: copy file
    ECHO moving %SOURCE_PATH%\!folder[%rand%]! to %DEST_PATH%\!folder[%rand%]!

    :: again
    GOTO loop

:done
    ECHO Done copying random folders, have fun!
```

Answer (score 2):

1.- You dont have taken in consideration the environment space exhausting. Maybe you can not create the array you are intending.

2.- `fsutil volume diskfree ...` always return the space in VOLUME, no matter if you indicate a directory

3.-`if` command do numeric comparisons ONLY when all the characters in both sides of the operator are numeric. Your () disables it, so (10) is less than (3)

Comment: Gonna look in to these things

Comment: Fixed that but now only some files output 0 as there size, and there is a file in them. (updated code in original thread)

Comment: Place echo command to show which source folder gets selected and check that folder contains files in it. FILES. If it contains folders but doesn't contain files, space in the directory will be 0 as your dir command is not recursive

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is working so far. waiting for the disk to get full if that works, this should be sufficient (not 100% perfect check but close enough)

code:

```
@ECHO off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET n=0
SET SOURCE_PATH=M:\src
SET DEST_PATH=E:\dest

:: get all folders in dir
FOR /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`DIR /b/a:d %SOURCE_PATH%`) do (
    SET /A n+=1     
    SET folder[!n!]=%%a
)

:loop
    :: selecting ranodm number
    SET /A rand=(n*%random%)/32768+1

    :: check for space
    for /F "tokens=3" %%a in ('dir /-c "%SOURCE_PATH%\!folder[%rand%]!" ^| findstr /c:"File(s)"') do set bytesfree=%%a
    set bytesfree=%bytesfree:,=%
    set /a NEEDED_SPACE=%bytesfree:~0,-3%

    for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('dir %DEST_PATH%\') do set bytesfree=%%a
    set bytesfree=%bytesfree:,=%
    set /a FREE_SPACE=%bytesfree:~0,-3%


    ECHO %FREE_SPACE% - %NEEDED_SPACE%
    IF %NEEDED_SPACE% GTR %FREE_SPACE% GOTO done

    :: check if file does not exits
    IF EXIST %DEST_PATH%\!folder[%rand%]! GOTO loop 

    :: copy file
    set src="%SOURCE_PATH%\!folder[%rand%]!\*"
    set dest= "%DEST_PATH%\!folder[%rand%]!\*"
    ECHO moving %src% to %dest%
    xcopy /s /e /i %src% %dest%

    :: again
    GOTO loop

:done
    ECHO Done copying random folders, have fun!
```